# THREE js Geometry UVs not mapping

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js

I am just trying to apply a loaded texture onto a mesh and use different UV coordinates for each face after the mesh is loaded. I believe I have followed all the necessary steps but I am not getting the desired results.

First, I specify the texture coordinates:

```
top_texture_uv = [new THREE.Vector2(0,0), new THREE.Vector2(8,0), new THREE.Vector2(8,8), new THREE.Vector2(0,8)];
side_texture_uv = [new THREE.Vector2(0,0), new THREE.Vector2(4,0), new THREE.Vector2(4,2), new THREE.Vector2(0,2)];
```

I would like the faces to repeat different times.

I then load the texture and update the geometry's face vertexes like the documentation specified. :

```
var txLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  txLoader.load(
    'textures/checker.gif',
    function ( texture ) {
      ground_segment.mesh.material.map = texture;
  //texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  ground_segment.mesh.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];

  ground_segment.mesh.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][0] = [top_texture_uv[0], top_texture_uv[1], top_texture_uv[3]];
  ground_segment.mesh.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][1] = [top_texture_uv[1], top_texture_uv[2], top_texture_uv[3]];

  ground_segment.mesh.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][2] = [top_texture_uv[0], top_texture_uv[1], top_texture_uv[3]];
  ground_segment.mesh.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][3] = [top_texture_uv[1], top_texture_uv[2], top_texture_uv[3]];

  ground_segment.mesh.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][4] = [top_texture_uv[0], top_texture_uv[1], top_texture_uv[3]];
  ground_segment.mesh.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][5] = [top_texture_uv[1], top_texture_uv[2], top_texture_uv[3]];

  ground_segment.mesh.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][6] = [top_texture_uv[0], top_texture_uv[1], top_texture_uv[3]];
  ground_segment.mesh.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][7] = [top_texture_uv[1], top_texture_uv[2], top_texture_uv[3]];

  ground_segment.mesh.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][8] = [top_texture_uv[0], top_texture_uv[1], top_texture_uv[3]];
  ground_segment.mesh.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][9] = [top_texture_uv[1], top_texture_uv[2], top_texture_uv[3]];

  ground_segment.mesh.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][10] = [top_texture_uv[0], top_texture_uv[1], top_texture_uv[3]];
  ground_segment.mesh.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][11] = [top_texture_uv[1], top_texture_uv[2], top_texture_uv[3]];


  ground_segment.mesh.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
  ground_segment.mesh.material.needsUpdate = true;
    }
  );
```

Mapping facevertices seems to have no effect.

Doing this doesn't work as it just takes the loaded texture and maps it without repeating on every face of the object, which is not what I would like to do. How do I make the geometry reflect the UV coordinate changes that I desire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `THREE.Geometry` and want to update the UVs after the geometry has been rendered.

Do not reassign the array like so:

```
mesh.geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ] = new THREE.Vector2( u, v ); // invalid
```

Instead, use this pattern:

```
mesh.geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ].copy( uv ); // or .set( u, v )

mesh.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true; // required only if geometry has been rendered
```

three.js r.84

Comment: Hm. I tried both copy and set options, but it's still not behaving correctly. Do I have to change them for all the faces? so 12 faces in total? Also, I should not clear the faceVertexes before copying over the uv coordinates because I need the vector there in order to access the copy method, correct?

Comment: Do not reassign any arrays; just replace values in the existing arrays. Of course, it is OK to replace only the values you want to change.